# Using method 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

Getting an error at (private int >>>TotArray<< (int[,] array)) 
Which tells me I cannot return value. Can anyone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

What this code does is it supposed to add all the numbers of this 2 dimensional array.
But in the moment it does nothing.

```
    int[,] A = new int[3, 4] 
    { 
        { 4, -5, 12, -2},
        { -9, 15, 19, 6},
        { 18, -33, -1, 7}
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private int TotArray(int[,] array)//<<<<<< error
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int rows = array.GetLength(0);
        int cols = array.GetLength(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                sum += array[i, j];
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = ("The sum of the array is " + sum.ToString() + ".");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotArray(A);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting an error because your TotArray method isn't actually returning an int.

What happens if you switch it to the following:

```
private void TotArray(int[,] array)
```

And if that doesnt fix it, can you post the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Your return type is `int` but you are not returning anything from your method.If you don't want to return anything change return type to `void` or *return* something.

```
private int TotArray(int[,] array)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int cols = array.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            sum += array[i, j];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int sum = TotArray(A);
   richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("The sum of the array is {0}.", sum);
}
```

Comment: But if I return sum it doesnt do anything... doesnt give me any values no nothing

Comment: @TheBoringGuy I'm guessing, you are not storing the returning value into a variable.If you don't store it that means you are simply _ignoring_ it.

Comment: nvm I found the mistake I had to change private int to private void

Comment: Prefer this answer as it shows better separation of concerns. i.e. a method that totals an array only returns a total instead of also updating the value of a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
return sum;
```

At the end of you're TotArray method.

Then place(for testing)

```
Debug.WriteLine(TotArray(A));
```

In your calling code, run the program, check the output window and your sum should be returned in the output window.